# how to reenable mouseover event in jquery which has been disabled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a input field and when a mouse hovers in the input filed edit button appears after clicking button I have disabled mouseover event using jQuery, I want to reenable this mouseover event by click of button but it is not getting enabled.

Attaching the code I have done.

```js
$('#Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1').mouseover(function () {
        $('#Organaization_Desg_view_modal_desg_name_edit_icon1').show();
    });
    $('#Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1').mouseout(function () {
        $('#Organaization_Desg_view_modal_desg_name_edit_icon1').hide();
    });
    
    
    
    $('#Organaization_Desg_view_modal_desg_name_edit_icon1').click(function () {
    $('#view_modal_edit_desg_name1').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#save_view_desg_name1').show();
                          $('#Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1').off("mouseover");    //disables the mouseover event
    });
    
    
    $('#save_view_desg_name1').click(function () {    // save changes to input field
        $("#view_modal_edit_desg_name1").prop('disabled', true);
        $('#save_view_desg_name1').hide();
        
        $('#Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1').on("mouseover");   // this part of code is not working
    });
```

```css
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1">
<input type="text" id="view_modal_edit_desg_name1" class="Organaization_Desg_input_box " disabled value="Public Relationship Officer" />

<button id="Organaization_Desg_view_modal_desg_name_edit_icon1" class="hide">click to disable mouseover</button>
</div>

<button id="save_view_desg_name1" class="hide"> click to enable mouseover</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is that you should write `mouseover` and `mouseout` functions in this code, as well as `$('#save_view_desg_name1').click(function () {`

```js
$('#Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1').mouseover(function () {
    $('#Organaization_Desg_view_modal_desg_name_edit_icon1').show();
});
$('#Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1').mouseout(function () {
    $('#Organaization_Desg_view_modal_desg_name_edit_icon1').hide();
});

$('#Organaization_Desg_view_modal_desg_name_edit_icon1').click(function () {
    $('#view_modal_edit_desg_name1').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#save_view_desg_name1').show();
    $('#Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1').off("mouseover"); //disables the mouseover event
});

$('#save_view_desg_name1').click(function () { // save changes to input field
    $("#view_modal_edit_desg_name1").prop('disabled', true);
    $('#save_view_desg_name1').hide();$('#Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1').mouseover(function () {
        $('#Organaization_Desg_view_modal_desg_name_edit_icon1').show();
    });
    $('#Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1').mouseout(function () {
        $('#Organaization_Desg_view_modal_desg_name_edit_icon1').hide();
    });
    
    // This part of code is not working
    // $('#Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1').on("mouseover");
});
```

```css
.hide{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Organaization_Desg_modal_view_Desg_input_hover1">
    <input
        type="text"
        id="view_modal_edit_desg_name1"
        class="Organaization_Desg_input_box"
        disabled
        value="Public Relationship Officer" />
    <button
        id="Organaization_Desg_view_modal_desg_name_edit_icon1"
        class="hide">
        click to disable mouseover
    </button>
</div>

<button id="save_view_desg_name1" class="hide">
    click to enable mouseover
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The more easier way is to make use of the "readonly" attribute of the input tag rather than disabling the mouseover events.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.disable').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.example-input').attr("readonly", true);
    $(this).siblings('.enable').css("visibility","visible");
    $(this).parent().find('button.disable').css("visibility","hidden");
  });
  $('.enable').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.example-input').attr("readonly", false);
    $(this).siblings('.disable').css("visibility","visible");
    $(this).parent().find('button.enable').css("visibility","hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.example > .disable{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.example:hover > .disable{
  visibility: visible;
}
.enable{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  <input type="text" class="example-input"/>
  <button type="button" class="example-button disable">Click to disable</button>
  <button type="button" class="example-button enable">Click to enable</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution you have provide works the first time but after once the button has remained displayed, first button should only be visible when you hover on input field